# I want to split this component to component which is rendered by container

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I don't know how to change this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../../_actions/user_action";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginPage = (props) => {

const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");

const onEmailHandler = (event) => {
setEmail(event.currentTarget.value);
};
const onPasswordHandler = (event) => {
setPassword(event.currentTarget.value);
};
const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

let body = {
  email: Email,
  password: Password,
};

dispatch(loginUser(body)).then((response) => {
  if (response.payload.loginSuccess) {
    props.history.push("/");
  } else {
    alert("Error");
  }
},[]);
};

return (
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
  }}
>
  <form
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
    }}
    onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}
  >
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" value={Email} onChange={onEmailHandler} />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" value={Password} onChange={onPasswordHandler} />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
);
};

export default withRouter(LoginPage);
```

I want to move two of useState, onEmailHandler, onPasswordHandler, onSubmitHandler to container file. But, if I move these things to container file, I can't make body object which is essential for dispatching data. How can I split this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoist/lift all the state and behavior to the parent/container component, and pass state values and handlers to child/presentation component.

## Container

```
const LoginContainer = (props) => {
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onEmailHandler = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const onPasswordHandler = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let body = {
      email: Email,
      password: Password
    };

    dispatch(loginUser(body)).then((response) => {
      if (response.payload.loginSuccess) {
        props.history.push("/");
      } else {
        alert("Error");
      }
    }, []);
  };

  return (
    <LoginForm
      Email={Email}
      Password={Password}
      onEmailHandler={onEmailHandler}
      onPasswordHandler={onPasswordHandler}
      onSubmitHandler={onSubmitHandler}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter(LoginContainer);
```

## Login Form

```
const LoginForm = ({
  onSubmitHandler,
  Email,
  onEmailHandler,
  Password,
  onPasswordHandler
}) => (
  <div
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100vh"
    }}
  >
    <form
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
      onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}
    >
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" value={Email} onChange={onEmailHandler} />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" value={Password} onChange={onPasswordHandler} />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```